# Title attribute on Anchor (<a>) tag in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-2010

We are facing below issue in Microsoft Outlook Email 2010.
We are generating an Email having an HTML body from our application The email has multiple links to other pages using anchor tags.
When the user hovers over these links, the URL is shown in the tooltip.
It is required to suppress the URL shown on hover of these hyperlinks. 
We tried to use ‘title’ attribute of the anchor tag, but it seems to not work in Outlook; it still displays the entire URL on hover and ignores the title attribute.
for e.g.
Email HTML used:
    `<a title="" href="[some URL]" data-type="link" title="my custom tooltip">Click Here</a>`
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that it is Word that renders HTML in Outlook, not IE. If you can't make it work in Word, it won't work in Outlook either.